# SFTP example in Java with Jsch using Proxy Server

Tags: java, proxy, ftp, sftp, jsch

I am using a proxy server to connect remote host (for transferring files/ getting files from remote sftp).

A (app server)  -- > B (proxy server) --> C (remote sftp)

I am using Apache httpd in proxy server.

How can I send files to remote sftp through proxy? 
Can Anyone suggest a good example for sftp using proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

If your Java SFTP client supports HTTPS proxies and your server works as an HTTPS proxy (supports CONNECT verb of HTTP protocol) then you can connect to the remote server via the proxy. In other cases you are out of luck.